# What is the minimum Android version that support Custom URL scheme?

Tags: android

I just need to know the minimum Android version that support Custom URL scheme?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the version, but you could quickly test: `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d <url> <package>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "Custom URL scheme", you mean an `<activity>` that has an `<intent-filter>` that has a `<data>` for some unique scheme, that has been supported since API Level 1.